# How to make a HTTP POST request from Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, request, http-post

I've never done POSTs in Ruby before and I'm missing something simple.

I am trying to make this request:

```
curl -s -X POST "http://example.com:8280/purest/chatbot/actions/message" --data "message=hello there&rooms=myroom"
```

I have:

```
    url = "http://example.com:8280"
    uri = URI.parse(url)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.set_debug_output($stdout)

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/purest/chatbot/actions/message")
    request.body = "message=hey from me in ruby&rooms=myroom"

    response = http.request(request)
```

This is the output:

```
<- "POST /purest/chatbot/actions/message HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: Ruby\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: example.com:8280\r\nContent-Length: 60\r\n\r\n"
<- "message=hey from except now from ruby&rooms=myroom"
-> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 18:33:33 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n"
-> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Language: en-US\r\n"
-> "Session-Id: \r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
-> "X-Moawsl-Info: php_pid=52478;php_tte_ms=14.93;php_hit=250;php_cpu_ms=15.02;maxrss=223016;customer_id=;session_order_id=;\r\n"
-> "Server_Id: bo1.200.21\r\n"
-> "TXID: CuDIFVkCOX1KINAaSrUgAg==\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
-> "64\r\n"
reading 100 bytes...
-> "[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Bad Request: Content-Type not supported: \"}]Encoding type  is not supported."
read 100 bytes
reading 2 bytes...
-> "\r\n"
read 2 bytes
-> "0\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
Conn close
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: This isn't an answer per se but I use https://github.com/httprb/http mainly just because I think its cleaner than `Net::HTTP`.

Comment: What's the output that it's giving you?

Comment: @mysmallidea added

Comment: It appears the server doesn't support gzip encoding which is what is being asked for. You may want to modify the `Accept-Encoding` header. Personally I'd use something other than Net:HTTP though.

Comment: Any Idea how to change that

Comment: Ruby's Net::HTTP isn't a good first choice. There are [many different HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) that'll make it easier, almost trivial, to use POST. Net::HTTP is a good toolbox for creating a new client if you need all the low-level capabilities, but for general use it's too low-level.

Comment: Did you read and try the Net::HTTP POST examples? https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST and https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST+with+Multiple+Values or https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST Also, your message body doesn't look like it's encoded correctly.

Comment: Make sure you set your Content-Type header, use `request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and see if that helps (and make sure you url encode your message!)

Comment: i ended up using a one liner with RestClient. Thanks guys